# vector iterator not dereferencable in side scrolling shooter

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void MyScene::bulletTest() {
    std::vector<Bullet*>::iterator it = bulletVector.begin();
    //auto it = std::adjacent_find(bulletVector.begin(), bulletVector.end());
    while (it != bulletVector.end()) {
        std::vector<Enemy*>::iterator that = enemyVector.begin();
        //auto that = std::adjacent_find(enemyVector.begin(),`enter code here`enemyVector.end());
        while (that != enemyVector.end()) {
            if ((*it)->isCollidingWith((*that))) {
                Bullet* b = (*it);
                this->removeChild(b);
                it = bulletVector.erase(it);
                delete b;

                enemyDeSpawn();
            }
            else
            {
                it++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am trying to test my bullets on my enemies in a engine build by my teacher, altho i cant get it running, as soon as i shoot my enemy while there are more than one on the scene the game crashes.

i will link the source code of the engine for anyone interested,
https://github.com/rktrlng/rt2d

Comment: Just a thought, also double up the conditional of your inner while-loop to include the same condition as your outer while-loop. There's no sense in continuing once you're out of active bullets. Better still, `break` the inner while-loop once your bullet has been used and `it` is advanced via erase, assuming your bullets aren't multi-target aware. And obviously, advance `that` *somehow*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for the problem you have:

1. You never check if `it == bulletVector.end()` in the inner loop, so you don't know if you erase the last element in `bulletVector`.
2. In the inner loop you never update the iterator `that`, so if you modify the `enemyVector` in e.g. `enemyDeSpawn` you could invalidate it. Or at the very least you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: and these mistakes cause an attempt to dereference container.end() iterator. That's what "vector iterator not dereferencable" message means.